# Slim working on localhost but gives "Fatal error: class not found" on shared host

Tags: php, slim, fatal-error

I'm using Slim 3 to create an app. All works well in localhost (xampp) but when I try the same app on my shared host I get "fatal error: class not found" for each class called with **use**. Example:

login route

```
use \App\Middlewares\ValidationMiddleware;

$app->get('/login', 'AuthController:getSignIn')->setName('login')
->add($container->csrf)
->add(new ValidationMiddleware($container));
```

I get

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Middlewares\ValidationMiddleware' not found

but the class is there and in localhost it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if all directories and files has correct capitalisation.

For linux directory or file with name `Abc` is not the same as `abc`, but for windows it is equal